# Find $\int \sin(2x)\sqrt{1+3\cos^{2}(x)}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Is it humanly possible to integrate the following equation?
$$\int \sin(2x)\sqrt{1+3\cos^{2}(x)}\ dx$$

Comment: Yes, it is humanly possible.

Comment: $dx$ is missing ...

Comment: My apologies Zev. Only after I suggested the edit did I realize that you had edited the title already. I thought I was changing the title from "Integration, help!"

Comment: @Sujaan: No, let me offer my apologies - I often make my edits in quick succession instead of all at once, and I hadn't remembered that you might have submitted your title edit before I had. Nevermind, no worries :)

Answer (score 6):

Let $u=\cos^2(x)$, therefore $du=-2\cos(x)\sin(x)\ dx$:

$$\int\sin(2x)\sqrt{1+3\cos^2(x)}\ dx=-\int\sqrt{1+3u}\ du$$

Now, let $v=1+3u$ and $dv=3\ du$:

\begin{align*}
-\int\sqrt{1+3u}\ du&=-\frac13\int\sqrt v\ dv\\
&=-\frac{2v^{3/2}}9+C,\text{ where $C$ is a constant}\\
&=-\frac29(1+3u)^{\frac32}+C\\
&=\boxed{-\frac29(1+3\cos^2(x))^{\frac32}+C}
\end{align*}

Comment: How did you get from the second line to the third line? Third line to fourth line?

Comment: Substitute $v=1+3u$, and $u=\cos^2(x)$ back in ...

Comment: @Cecilly why are you confused by this? Have you been paying any attention in class at all?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Use substitution, and the fact that $\sin 2x = 2\sin x \cos x$.

Comment: Can you provide me with a full solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd try, and the reasons why I would want to:

Trig functions with **different** arguments are BAD!  And there's a simple way to get rid of $\sin(2x)$, so we get:$$\int 2\sin(x)\cos(x)\sqrt{1+3\cos^{2}(x)}\ dx$$with the $2$ easily moved out of the integration.

Next, you've got a function with one $\sin(x)$ and a mess of $\cos(x)$, and $\sin(x)$ is very close to the derivative of $\cos(x)$!  So if we try $$u=\cos(x)$$ $$du=-\sin(x) dx$$ we get $$-2\int u\sqrt{1+3u^2}\ du$$ So now all the trig is gone!

I still have an ugly expression (under a square root, too!), but I also have something close to the differential of the ugly expression.  So I'd try:$$v=1+3u^2$$ $$dv=6u\  du$$ $$u\   du=\frac{dv}{6}$$ giving:$$-\frac{1}{3}\int v^{\frac{1}{2}}\ dv$$This is an integral I can do.  And I'm human...